# Get custom audience by name using Facebook Marketing API

Tags: java, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to get/fetch a custom audience by it's name?

When I use `adAccount.getCustomAudiences()` it returns only id fields of Custom Audiences without any name or description data.

I want to check if an audience exists or not in order to add more users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
adAccount.getCustomAudiences().requestField("name").execute();
```

This returns all audiences with name fields.